# Dependency management for a small Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-management

What is the best practice when it comes to managing dependencies in a small java project?  Small meaning one Eclipse Java project.  I have 4 different third-party jars that I have added to the Eclipse build path.  I have had experience with Maven, but for this small scope, it doesn't seem like it would fit.  I have read about Gradle, but have not tried it.  What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Maven is appropriate even for small projects.  Have you looked at the m2e plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: I think Maven is too heavyweight for this project's scope.  One of the many reasons is that I would have to create and maintain a nexus repo server.

Comment: Are the 3rd party Jars public libraries? In that case you don't need to maintain a nexus repo server, just use the normal central one. Gradle still needs a repository (and also uses the maven central one). I use Maven for all  my small projects, it doesn't introduce any overheads at all (just the pom.xml in the project folder) and removes all the classpath and jar file dependency headaches.

Comment: I will setup and try maven.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Apache IvyIDE.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/

It allows you to manage your dependencies declared in an ivy.xml in your Java Eclipse projects.